# jQuery .val() doesnt return the value of an option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have some JavaScript-generated html code. The JavaScript generates the elements (option) in a drop down list (select). I then want to get the value of the selected option '1', however instead 'test' is returned.

The html is generated using:

```
var newSelect = document.createElement('option');
selectHTML = "<option value=\"" + 1 + "\">" + test + "</option>";
newSelect.innerHTML = selectHTML;
document.getElementById('siteID').add(newSelect);
```

I have then tried the following methods to get the value of the selected option:

```
var siteId = $('#siteID').val(); // returns 'test'
var siteId2 = $('#siteID').data("value"); // returns undefined
var siteId3 = $('#siteID').attr("value"); // returns undefined
var siteId4 = $('#siteID').prop("value"); // returns 'test'
```

Comment: use jquery, for ex- $('#example').append('<option value="foo" selected="selected">Foo</option>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very strange way to create your option  - you create an option and then insert an option string as innerHTML

**Fixed code** (see example later)

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value=1;
opt.text="test"
document.getElementById('siteID').appendChild(opt);
```

Also you do not actually select the option, so the value will be whatever the browser thinks is selected

Why not use jQuery?

```js
$("<option />", { value: 1, text: "test" }).appendTo('#siteID1')
$('#siteID1').prop("selectedIndex", 1); // NOW the value is 1

console.log(
  $('#siteID1').val()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="siteID1">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Your code:

```js
var test ="Test";
var newSelect = document.createElement('option'),
   selectHTML = "<option value=\"" + 1 + "\">" + test + "</option>";
newSelect.innerHTML = selectHTML;
document.getElementById('siteID').add(newSelect);
console.log(document.getElementById('siteID').outerHTML)
```

```html
<select id="siteID">
</select>
```

Your FIXED code

```js
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value=1;
opt.text="test"
document.getElementById('siteID').appendChild(opt);

console.log(document.getElementById('siteID').value, $('#siteID').val())
console.log(document.getElementById('siteID').outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="siteID">
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You created the option `newSelect` then you try to insert an option inside of it with `innerHTML` which is where you went wrong.
This is what you should have done.

```
var newSelect = document.createElement('option');
newSelect.innerHTML = 'test';
newSelect.value= '1';
document.getElementById('siteID').add(newSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```js
var test = 'test';
selectHTML = "<option value=\"" + 1 + "\">" + test + "</option>";
$("#siteID").append(selectHTML);

var siteId = $('#siteID').val(); 
console.log(siteId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="siteID"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need remove `//selectHTML = "<option value=" + 1 + ">" + test + "</option>";`

And change to `newSelect.value = 1;` for add value to option by javascript

```
newSelect.innerHTML = test;
newSelect.value = 1;
```

```js
var newSelect = document.createElement('option');
var test = 'test';
//selectHTML = "<option value=" + 1 + ">" + test + "</option>";
newSelect.innerHTML = test;
newSelect.value = 1;
document.getElementById('siteID').appendChild(newSelect);

$(document).ready(function(){
var siteId = $('#siteID').val(); // r
console.log(siteId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='siteID'>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can first create the Select tag and after that try to append the option tag. I have attached the code as below:

```js
// create the select tag and append with the main div tag
var string = '<select id="dropdown_tag"></select>';
$("#test").append(string);

// create as many option you want and append with the select tag
var newSelect = document.createElement('option');
selectHTML = "<option>---select---</option>";
selectHTML += "<option value='1'>1</option>";
selectHTML += "<option value='2'>2</option>";
$("#dropdown_tag").append(selectHTML);

// Onchange event of dropdown tag
$(document).on('change',"#dropdown_tag", function()
{
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Dropdowm:<div id='test'></div>
```